# Table exists but doesn't appear SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've used the query

```
SELECT TOP (1000000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS N
INTO #Tally3
```

and it worked. But I can't find the table `#TALLY3` in SQL Server, even after refreshing.

What is weird is that after executing

```
SELECT * 
INTO test 
FROM table1
```

the table test did appear and I was able to see it.

What's even weirder,

```
SELECT * FROM #TALLY3
```

works now even though it doesn't appear and SQL Server underlines `#TALLY3` in red because it thinks it doesn't exist:

[image]

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a #temporary table. It's created in `tempdb`, not your user database. You're not going to find it in Object Explorer, and it's only visible in the query window that created it. It will disappear when that session ends.

Comment: Oh I did not know `#` means temporary, thanks!!

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows: Both `#` and `##` have a special meaning at the beginning of SQL Server table names. This is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#temporary-tables

Comment: Quick question, why does deleting the temporary table not work `Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 2
Cannot drop the table '#Tally3', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.`

Comment: I can't `SELECT INTO #TALLY3` anymore because it says it already exists and I can't drop it either.

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows You can try this if you really need to drop it (it will vanish anyway when the session closes) `IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TALLY3') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TALLY3;`

Comment: In newer SQL Server versions `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TALLY3;`.